# I want vim YouCompleteMe plugin to complete parenthesis

Tags: vim

I installed YCM plugin. And I want YCM to complete left, right parenthesis.

I made a simple cpp source file. In main function, I declared

```
vector<int> v(10, 0);
```

when I pressed dot(.), vector member functions were shown.

[member functions were shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzjkD.png)

Then, I pressed downward arrow key and reached `empty()` function.

Everytime I press arrow key, YCM automatically complete function name. When I move recommendation menu, YCM ONLY complete function name. does not complete parenthesis. It is reasonable.

[YCM complete function name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp9zt.png)

Finally, I pressed enter key(I chosed `empty()` function). However YCM did not complete parenthesis.

> v.empty

So, I need to manually type left and right parenthesis.

I expected that when I pressed enter, YCM would complete parenthesis as well.

Is it possible to make YCM complete parenthesis?

below is my `~/.vimrc` config.

```
let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1
set completeopt-=preview
let g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt = 0
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

Plugin 'delimitMate.vim'
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'AutoComplPop'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'L9'
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'


call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0
"To avoid conflict snippets
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-j>', '<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-k>', '<Up>']
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1
let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 0
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 0
let g:ycm_echo_current_diagnostic = 0
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1

set backspace=2
if has("syntax")
    syntax on
endif
set nu
set nuw=9
set magic
set ls=2
set sc
set cursorline
"set autoindent
set ts=4
set shiftwidth=4
set laststatus=2
set statusline=\ %<%l:%v\ [%P]%=%a\ %h%m%r\ %F\
set hlsearch
set scrolloff=2
set showmatch
set showmode
set smarttab
set smartindent
set softtabstop=4
set tabstop=4
set ruler
set incsearch
set title
set wrap
set scrollbind
set background=dark

hi Comment term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=green
syntax enable

" AutoComplPop customizing
function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.')-1
    if !col||getline('.')[col-1]!~'\k'
        return "\<TAB>"
    else
        if pumvisible()
            return "\<C-N>"
        else
            return "\<C-N>\<C-P>"
        end
    endif
endfunction
" AutoComplPop end


inoremap <TAB> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>
hi Pmenu ctermbg=blue
hi PmenuSel ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=black
hi PmenuSbar ctermbg=red


"DelimitMate customizing
"BreakLine: Return TRUE if in the middle of {} or () in INSERT mode
fun BreakLine()
  if (mode() == 'i')
    return ((getline(".")[col(".")-2] == '{' && getline(".")[col(".")-1] == '}') ||
          \(getline(".")[col(".")-2] == '(' && getline(".")[col(".")-1] == ')'))
  else
    return 0
  endif
endfun

" Remap <Enter> to split the line and insert a new line in between if
" BreakLine return True
inoremap <expr> <CR> BreakLine() ? "<CR><ESC>O" : "<CR>"
"DelimitMate end
```

Comment: Might have more luck over in http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1) C is not C++ is not C! 2) This is not related to the language C. 3) Nor is it related to Linux. 4) Don't spam tags.

Comment: I am sorry. I will be more cautious.